# Pandas Dataframe: loop and calculate mean and std over increasing number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Basically, I have a table with 20 attributes and a value. I want to find the lowest number of attributes needed for where the std = 0 - (i.e. where the level of granularity is perfect to allow a 1:1).

I want to set up a loop If hard coded using column names, it would look like this:

```
for iter in range(1,21):
  dfcalc = df.groupby("LINE_NUM")["RATIO"].agg([np.mean, np.std])
  dfcalc = df.groupby("LINE_NUM","TYPE")["RATIO"].agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

How can I use the iter variable in loop to define the columns I want to group by?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you could do this:

```
for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1):
    df.groupby(df.columns[:i].tolist()).agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

(`iter` is the name of a builtin function)

You can also use `.iloc` for [integer-based indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

Comment: I get "ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length". Also, doesn't it need to specify the column on which it should do mean and std:

Comment: import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A','A', 'C', 7], ['W','C', 'D', 8], ['W','A', 'C', 9]]),columns=['att1', 'att2', 'att3','ratio'])

for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1):
    df.groupby(df.columns[:i]).agg([np.mean, np.std])